# Customize back navigation react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to control the back navigation, I am using react-navigation library for routing. I have some pages main pages, profile page and profile_edit page. when I navigate to profile_edit through profile page, after doing some action in profile_edit I navigate to profile page. Now if I press back button I want to navigate to some other page instead of profile_edit page.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom **headerLeft**

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
  static  navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title:  'Header Title',
     headerLeft: <Icon name={'arrow-left'} 
                    onPress={ () => { navigation.navigate("YourScreen") }} />
  });

    render() {
        return (<View> ... </View>)
    }
}
```